# What free software can I use for GoPro fisheye lens correction?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, photoshop

What free software can I use on Ubuntu (or Windows) to correct GoPro fisheye lens effect on a video (or at least an image)?

Answer (score 4):

### Gimp

You can use Gimp in Ubuntu Linux to correct fishlens effects in images:

[How to Correct Fisheye in GIMP](http://classroom.synonym.com/correct-fisheye-gimp-19646.html)

---

### ffmpeg + frei0r

For videos:

[How to remove fisheye from videos on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/800846/how-to-remove-fisheye-from-videos-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

**[GIMP Lensfun](https://seebk.github.io/GIMP-Lensfun/)** supports GoPro so you can easily fix with that.

It recognizes camera parameters so it is better than the GIMP plugin above.

Comment: you could advise how to get & use this tool...

Comment: APT has `gimp-lensfun` package. Problem is, GoPro is not present on the list of supported cameras even tho the underlying database lists GoPro.